# Sum elements of tuples in RDD with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD with tuples<string, int>. I want to sum all the elements.

This is the relevant part, previously I have all the imports and the spark_conf and spark_context defined

```py
films = spark_context \
        .textFile(sys.argv[1]) \
        .map(lambda row : (row.split(",")[0],1))\
        .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)

sum_elements = films.reduce(lambda a,b: a[1]+b[1])
```

This throws an error saying that b is not subscriptable but if I don't put an index it says it's a tuple.
Probably is something super obvious that I'm overlooking but I've not been able of solving it so far.

Comment: Please provide as input text file and the relevant output.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is returning the tuple and indexing to get the sum of b (a [string],b [int]) is throwing the error. You should transform the tuples into integers and then sum b.

```
films = spark_context \
        .textFile(sys.argv[1]) \
        .map(lambda row : (row.split(",")[0],1))\
        .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)

sum_elements = films.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
print(sum_elements)
```